# How do I pass a display to a qsub command?

Tags: java, bash, shell, x11, display

I am running a bash script that, among other things, runs a java program that can be used via GUI or via command line (depending on a parameter).

```
splitstree --commandLineMode --commandFile comm.txt --version --verbose
```

**EDIT:**

When I run it via normal command line or via GUI, it works perfectly. If I `echo` this command into a file and `$(cat file)` it also works, and it works as well when I integrate it into a bash script and run the bash script.

If I `qsub` it to the cluster where I am doing the work, I get an error about a missing display:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed 
an operation which requires it.
```

I tried to `export DISPLAY=:0.0` within the bash script but the error didn't change.

**EDIT 2:**

If I pass the DISPLAY variable to the `qsub` command, the error goes away but the program terminates with an exit status of 1. Like:

```
qsub -v DISPLAY <job_file>
```

It also says `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096M` but performing `unset` on this variable didn't change the exit status (so probably is not harming the process).

Re-running the same command outside of `qsub` (that is: simply copy-paste the cmd into the shell) work perfectly again.

Any suggestion on how to make it so that the `qsub` command correctly passes the display information to the cluster node?

Comment: Maybe you can circumvent the pipe by using process substitution `<(...)`. Please show us the full command you are using.

Comment: The issue is because the program you are running still uses things that need a GUI when run in command line mode

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the display run Java with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` property, as explained in [Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

Alternatively, if your program can't run headless, you can try using [Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). It comes with `xvfb-run` command, take a look at [Running without a Display](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Running-without-a-Display) wiki:

```
xvfb-run java MainClass
```

or by configuring `DISPLAY` environment variable:

```
sudo Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 </dev/null &
export DISPLAY=":1"
java MainClass
```

Answer (score 0):

When in a headless environment, you need to use GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() in your code to avoid doing anything that requires AWT components. That means you can't do any input/output, of course.